# VBA Office 2007 Create 2003 Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Since a few days I'm using MS Access 2007 in a certian process.
In my VBA code I use: **CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")**

In Access 2003 a document was created in 2000-2003 format.
Now in Access 2007 VBA enforces the new format. This causes problems in some additional coding.

Any suggestions how to enforce older format (2000-2003) through VBA?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `SaveAs` method with its second parameter [`FileFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.fileformat.aspx) as [`xlExcel8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet with a second param of acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8